# Angularjs Post to SQL-server

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, database, post

I have a little problem with my post php file. I get it to post to my database but I can't figure it out how to get the name of the player from angularjs.

```
$scope.addPlayer = function (playerName){

    alert(playerName);

    $http.post("insert.php",{'Name': playerName})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(status);
        });
  };
```

And here is my php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "pswrd";
$dbname = "db_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Pelaaja (Name, Games, Penalty, Alc, Wins, Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Color)
VALUES (Name, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'No color')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So how should I get the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem, if someone ever encounters the same problem.

```js
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$Name = $request->Name;

var_dump($Name);
print_r($Name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Pelaaja (Name, Games, Penalty, Alc, Wins, Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Color)
VALUES ('$Name', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'No color')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your post value in php file like

```
$name = $_POST['Name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Pelaaja (Name, Games, Penalty, Alc, Wins, Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Color)
VALUES ('$name', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'No color')";
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! I tried this and still the name is empty in my database although everything else gets posted.  :/